# Como fazer um form nunca desaparecer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Como eu posso fazer um form invisível apenas com o texto aparecendo,sem os botões apenas um texto,nunca desaparecer quando selecionado outra janela?
um print:http://prnt.sc/ehlx3i

Quando seleciono outra janela ele some,é possível ele sempre aparecer?

Obg pela atenção.

Answer (score 2):

No construtor do form faça:

```
public Form1()
{
    //Deixa o form transparente
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Turquoise;
    this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

    //Faz o form ficar na frente das outras aplicações
    this.TopMost = true;
}
```

Isso dá uma aparência de transparente, com tudo, os cantos dos form ficarão um pouco estranhos.

Não é possível deixar o form 100% transparente (sem detalhes).

Comment: Olá discordo de você,deixei um sem detalhes,mas o processo fica.Link:http://prnt.sc/ehyoa3

Comment: Processo? Ainda bem que ele continua. Se não continuasse a aplicação não funcionaria. Acho que você se refere á barra de tarefas, certo? Se for isso coloque `this.ShowInTaskbar = false`